# Solr delete by query: error 400, undefined field productId

Tags: solr

When i attempt to delete a document using a [query](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22delete.22_documents_by_ID_and_by_Query), like so:

http://localhost:8090/solr/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3EproductId%3A38214%3C%2Fquery%3E%3C%2Fdelete%3E

I get this:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">400</int>
<int name="QTime">49</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
<str name="msg">undefined field productId</str>
<int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

According to http://localhost:8090/solr/#/webshop/schema productId is present:

```
<field name="productId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="false" />
[...]
<uniqueKey>productId</uniqueKey>
```

This works fine: http://localhost:8090/solr/webshop/select?q=productId%3A38214&wt=json&indent=true

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/webshop/

This works: http://localhost:8090/solr/webshop/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3EproductId%3A%2738214%27%3C%2Fquery%3E%3C%2Fdelete%3E

I feel a little stupid now.